# get lower bound iterator of search string from set. Here, strings length in set are less than search string length

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, lower-bound

I want the lower bound iterator of search string from set. Here, strings length in set are less than search string length.

I mean, set has strings like `{ "/Applications", "/Bpplications", "/Cpplications", "/Dpplications", "/Library/caches", "/opt/local", "/usr/local" };`.

My search string is like `/Cpplications/test/sample.txt`

Here I need the the lower bound iterator from set which matches substring of search string i.e. iterator from `/Cpplications` . But, I am getting iterator of `/Dpplications` with my below code snippet.

Can anyone help to fix this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
bool starts_with(string a, string b) {
    return a.compare(0, a.length(), b) < 0;
}
int main()
{
    // Input set
    std::set<string> s{ "/Applications", "/Bpplications", "/Cpplications", "/Dpplications", "/Library/caches", "/opt/local", "/usr/local" };
    
    std::set<string>::iterator low11;
    low11 = std::lower_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), "/Cpplications/test/sample.txt", starts_with);
    
    std::cout << "lower_bound:\n";
    for (;low11 != s.end(); low11++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n"<< (*low11);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're doing something very strange. Do you understand that `std::lower_bound` performs a linear search here, since `std::set` doesn't provide random-access iterators?

Comment: you want to first match? `std::lower_bound` only makes sense when the range is partioned with respect to the predicate. Usually that means that the range is sorted with respect to the predicate, which doesnt make much sense here, because if it would be sorted you'd already know the answer. The `set` is only sorted with respect to `<`

Comment: Can you say what element you need to find without refering to "lower bound"?

Comment: And what's up with the comparator? Why do you skip the last character? My crystal ball says you want `s.upper_bound(...)` with the default comparator, then decrement the resulting iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparator only does what you want if the left argument is longer than the right argument. `std::lower_bound` will call it with the searched-for value in both positions to determine equivalence.

This comparison will do the correct thing for your case, but it isn't a strict weak order, so it can't be used where you need a *Compare*, e.g. for sorting.

```
bool starts_with(std::string_view a, std::string_view b) {
    auto size = std::min(a.size(), b.size());
    return a.substr(0, size) < b.substr(0, size);
}
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/131766c31f600e32)

A different approach is to look at the element prior to the upper bound, and see if that has the correct prefix. N.b. you will have to be careful with the edges of the search range.

```
std::set<std::string> s{ "/Applications", "/Bpplications", "/Cpplications", "/Dpplications", "/Library/caches", "/opt/local", "/usr/local" };
std::string n{"/Cpplications/test/sample.txt"};

auto low11 = s.upper_bound(n);
if (low11 != s.begin()) low11--;
if (low11 != s.end() && n.starts_with(*low11)) {
    std::cout << "lower_bound:\n" << *low11;
}
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e99f19c8c91b7aa)

Comment: Thanks caleth. Second solution looks fine to me. But I am using some set of structure which has string as one param. But I am getting below compilation error.
```/Solution.cpp: In function 'int main()':
./Solution.cpp:34:49: error: no matching function for call to 'implfile_list::lower_bound(const char [22])'
  auto it = f.lower_bound("/usr/local/test/a.txt");
                                                 ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.4.0/set:61:0,
                 from ./Solution.cpp:3:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.4.0/bits/stl_set.h:729:7: note: cande: std::set...```

Comment: My code:
```#include <set>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
struct impl {
    std::string f;
    impl_file(std::string fn): f(fn) {}
    bool operator<(const impl_file& i){
        return f < i.f;
    }
};
struct impl_list: public std::set<impl> {};
int main()
{
   impl_list f; f.emplace(impl("/Applications")); f.emplace(impl("/opt/local"));f.emplace(impl("/usr/local"));
 auto it = f.lower_bound("/usr/local/test/a.txt");
   if (it != (s.begin())) it--;
 if (it != s.end())
  cout << (*it) << endl;
 else
  cout << "larger" << endl;
return 0
}```

Comment: @RednamNagendra there's a whole bunch of typos there. [Is this what you want](https://godbolt.org/z/fo85W5bcK)

Comment: You weren't providing a `<` for `impl` and `char[]`